# How to version control patched dependencies?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Using cabal sandboxes, how do I specify that my project depends on a patched version of a library, then check that dependency into version control?

I know I can use `cabal sandbox add-source` to add a dependency on a patched version, but that just changes something locally right? Any other programmer would have to remember to run that command in order to build the project.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to constrain the version for installation.

1. Add lower and upper bounds to package versions in the cabal file, [example of such a file here](https://github.com/Soostone/hadron/blob/master/hadron.cabal)
2. Additionally, you can override the settings in the .cabal file with the flag constraint like so: `cabal install --constraint="bar-2.1"`

To remove a specific version of a package:

- In a sandbox you can unregister a version with `cabal sandbox hc-pkg unregister bar-2.1`
- Global unregistering can be done with this command outside of sandbox `ghc-pkg unregister bar-2.1`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but what I'm asking is if there is a way to check in a dependency on a patched / local source for a package. Like when you run `cabal sandbox add-source`. Can I check the result of that in somehow?

Comment: If I understand correctly - you're collaborating on a project and want to include a local or private version of a dependency that is not listed on hackage. You want to add it to a sandbox, and verify the version number?

Comment: Btw, to list version numbers of dependencies in a sandbox, you can use `$ cabal -v sandbox hc-pkg list` and grep for specific items in the list.

Comment: Very close, except I don't think the version number matters. The real-world scenario might be that I find a missing feature in a published database driver. I fork his repository, add the new feature, and issue a pull request. I want to allow my application to depend on the forked version while the author reviews it, and for a collaborator to be able to compile the project with `cabal install`.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you for clarifying. You would use `cabal sandbox add-source /path/to/dependency` and your collaborators would all use the same command. This would allow you to use a local version instead of the ones listed on hackage. `cabal sandbox list-sources` to see what the sources were registered to the sandbox

Comment: It appears there is no way to check the result of add-source into a repo right now. Recommended workaround from #haskell is to have a bash script that does this. Thanks for your help @katychuang!